# Creating a future list from a future in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying to return a Future<List> in an async function, which is constructed when another Future completes.

```
Future<List<String>> myFunc() async {
  <Future<List<String>> eventDescriptions;

  googleCalendarApi.events.list('primary').then((events) => {
    eventDescriptions = events.items.map((e) => e.description).toList();
  }

  return eventDescriptions;
```

I had assumed that the completion of the `googleCalendarApi.events.list()` would asynchronously create the eventDescriptions such that it would be happy to do the Future assignment (in the Future).

But Flutter complains about the assignment because the result is a List not a Future<List> even though the assignment is done in the future!

Comment: your `myFunc` is an `async` function so you can use `await` instead of `Future.then` method - it is much more simple way - more: https://dart.dev/codelabs/async-await

Comment: add await before googleCalendarApi.events.list

Comment: Concerning await, I had assumed this effectively turns an asynchronously completing function into a synchronous one.  If I do, `events = await googleCalendarApi.events;` won't that stall the execution of the function until it completes?  I'll read through that page in more detail, I think it's just me spending too much time working in C to bend my mind around Futures!

Comment: "[...] turns an asynchronously completing function into a synchronous one" - no, `await` can only be used inside `async` function and this function always returns a `Future`

Comment: Been playing with DartPad to understand what happens when you put in an await (inside an async function).  So to my understanding, the thread of execution returns to the calling function as soon as the async function hits the first await (and returns the uncompleted Future).  Then the async function will continue execution (when it can) until it completes the Future.  Makes sense now!

Comment: yes, this is how it works - you can even do stuff like `while(true) { doSomething(); await Future.delayed(duration); }` and no, it will not block your app

Answer (score 1):

So this is my solution to the problem, this does do the right thing now I understand the execution of an async function.

```
Future<List<String>> myFunc() async {
    Events events = await googleCalendarApi.events.list('primary',
        timeMin: DateTime.now(), singleEvents: true, orderBy: 'startTime');

    return events.items!.map((e) => e.description).whereType<String>().toList();
  }
```

Comment: Looks ok, but it's unclear a little bit. Could be added logic - why this fixes your issue.